Keep Data on App Uninstall Flutter Secure Storage
I'm using flutter_secure_storage: 8.0.0 in my App to keep user data, but the customer keep losing its data.
I'm not sure if when he updates the app the data is erased or before install a new version he uninstalls the app.
There is some way to persist this data even on app uninstall?
Enable hasFragileUserData might be a way on Android, but how about iOS?
Storage the data in an encrypt file may be the last alternative.
My Storage code:
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart' as fss;

class FlutterSecureStorage implements SecureStorageInterface {
  final _storage = const fss.FlutterSecureStorage();

  @override
  Future<void> deleteValue({required String key}) async {
    try {
      await _storage.delete(key: key);
    } on PlatformException catch (e, s) {
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<String> getValue({required String key}) async {
    try {
      final value = await _storage.read(key: key);
      return value ?? '';
    } on PlatformException catch (e, s) {
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setValue({required String value, required String key}) async {
    try {
      await _storage.write(key: key, value: value);
    } on PlatformException catch (e, s) {
    }
  }
}

